# Use Scala's reflection API for dynamic factory class instantiation

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-2.10

I am new to the Scala reflection capabilities. I was wondering if it possible to build a factory object that delivers instantiations of different classes according to a type-parameter.

The code below does not work but It describes in a minimal example what I am trying to achieve. I left out the code for the A1Factory and A2Factory because they don't matter here.

```
sealed abstract class A

class A1 extends A

class A2 extends A

object Factory {
  def apply[T <: A]() = {
    classOf[T] match {
      case x: A1 => new A1Factory()
      case x: A2 => new A2Factory()
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
type currentType = A1
val factory = Factory[currentType]()
```

And factory is of type *A1Factory*.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible by telling the compiler to retain runtime types using an implicit ClassTag:

```
object Factory {
    def apply[T <: A]()(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]) = {
    val A1 = classOf[A1]
    val A2 = classOf[A2]
    classTag[T].runtimeClass match {
        case A1 => new A1Factory()
        case A2 => new A2Factory()
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider `TypeTags` to avoid erasure of parameters of `T`.